# static_cast cannot convert from void* to size_t error in C++ in VS 2010

Tags: c++

I am having following code which I am getting following error

> error C2036: 'void *' : unknown size
>   error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'size_t'

at line

```
void *addr = static_cast <void*> (static_cast <size_t> (mem + bytesAlreadyAllocated));
```

My question is why I am getting above errors and how to get rid of these errors?

Thanks for help.

```
class MemoryChunk {
public:
    MemoryChunk (MemoryChunk *nextChunk, size_t chunkSize);
    ~MemoryChunk() {delete mem; }

    inline void *alloc (size_t size);
    inline void free (void* someElement);

    // Pointer to next memory chunk on the list.
    MemoryChunk *nextMemChunk() {return next;}
    // How much space do we have left on this memory chunk?
    size_t spaceAvailable() { return chunkSize - bytesAlreadyAllocated; }

    // this is the default size of a single memory chunk.
    enum { DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 4096 };
private:

    // The MemoryChunk class is a cleaner version of NextOnFreeList. It separates the next pointer from
    // the actual memory used for the allocated object. It uses explicit next and mem pointers, with no 
    // need for casting.

    MemoryChunk *next;
    void *mem;

    // The size of a single memory chunk.
    size_t chunkSize;
    // This many bytes already allocated on the current memory chunk.
    size_t bytesAlreadyAllocated;
};

MemoryChunk::MemoryChunk(MemoryChunk *nextChunk, size_t reqSize) {
    chunkSize = (reqSize > DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE) ? reqSize : DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE;
    next = nextChunk;
    bytesAlreadyAllocated = 0;
    mem = new char [chunkSize];
}

void* MemoryChunk :: alloc (size_t requestSize) {
    void *addr = static_cast <void*> (static_cast <size_t> (mem + bytesAlreadyAllocated));
    bytesAlreadyAllocated += requestSize;
    return addr;
}

inline void MemoryChunk :: free (void *doomed) {}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Do you want the error explained? Do you want a workaround? Do you want to know if the error message is correct or if your code is legal?

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question but I think what you're trying to do can be done with: void *addr = static_cast<void *>(static_cast<char *>(mem) + bytesAlreadyAllocated) .

Comment: Yep. Adding an integer to a `void *` is undefined behavior.

Comment: cast to char * then add the offset.

Comment: The reason by the way that the compiler complains is that you can't up-cast from a pointer (void *) to a size_t as one is not a subtype of the other. You'd have to use C style unchecked casting for that.

Answer (score 4):

the expression:

```
static_cast <size_t> (mem + bytesAlreadyAllocated)
```

applies an offset using a type of undefined size (`void`). since `void` has no size, the program is ill formed.

`char*` is a suitable pointer for your usage in this scenario. for example:

```
`char* mem;`
 // and
 char* addr(mem + bytesAlreadyAllocated);
```

**Update**

So in the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    const int array[3] = {-1, 0, 1};
    std::cout << *(array + 0) << ", "
      << *(array + 1) << ", " << *(array + 2) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `-1, 0, 1`. The element offsets are applied based on the size and type of the array elements. With `void` -- size is not proper.

Comment: Yep. 5.7 lists all the legal cases where you can add to a pointer. This is not one of them.

Comment: Can you please eloborate? I am new to C++ type casting. Thanks!

Comment: @venkysmarty i expanded to demonstrate how you would overcome the problem. working on another update…